# iOS 5 ARC lazy image loading library

Tags: ios, uiimageview, lazy-loading, automatic-ref-counting

Is there an iOS 5 arc compatible lazy Image loading library?  I've not found one.

My next thought is to make EGOlazyloading a compiled library and link it to my project.  Would that work? Any pointers on going about?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote one. You can download it here:

https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView

Alternatively, if you do want to use EGO, or some other library, select Edit>Refactor>Convert to ARC and in the dialog that comes up there's a little drop down to select which files to convert.

Just tick the files that should be converted to ARC and un-tick ones which shouldn't be. If a file is already using ARC then leave it ticked (it won't double convert it).

That gives you the option of either trying to convert the library files to ARC or to leave them alone. Files that are unticked will be marked with the `-fno-objc-arc` flag automatically so you won't have to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Byron, you could just use a regular library like EGOlazyloading you suggested and order the compiler not to use ARC on those specific files by adding the flag `-fno-objc-arc` in "Build Phases -> Compile Sources"